# JavaScript buidling a hierarchical tree and make out put nested UL/LI inside expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have below code from another request it's working fine, it's creating a hierarchical tree (deep level). But I need the output instead of **JSON** to be **HTML UL/LI nested** or **select menu parent and child**

The idea here is: need to do category and subcategory like WordPress. I will use it inside nodejs expressjs

**Here is the data**

```
var items = [
{"Id": "1", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "2"},
{"Id": "2", "Name": "abc", "Parent": ""},
{"Id": "3", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "5"},
{"Id": "4", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "2"},
{"Id": "5", "Name": "abc", "Parent": ""},
{"Id": "6", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "2"},
{"Id": "7", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "6"},
{"Id": "8", "Name": "abc", "Parent": "6"},
 {"Id": "9", "Name": "abz", "Parent": "8"}];
```

**A function that builds tree**

```
function buildHierarchy(arry) {

var roots = [], children = {};

// find the top level nodes and hash the children based on parent
for (var i = 0, len = arry.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var item = arry[i],
        p = item.Parent,
        target = !p ? roots : (children[p] || (children[p] = []));

    target.push({ value: item });
}

// function to recursively build the tree
var findChildren = function(parent) {
    if (children[parent.value.Id]) {
        parent.children = children[parent.value.Id];
        for (var i = 0, len = parent.children.length; i < len; ++i) {
            findChildren(parent.children[i]);
        }
    }
};

// enumerate through to handle the case where there are multiple roots
for (var i = 0, len = roots.length; i < len; ++i) {
    findChildren(roots[i]);
}

return roots;}
console.log(buildHierarchy(items));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with this simple recursive function

```
function treeToHtml(tree) {
    var listItems = tree.map(function(node){
      var result = `<li>${node.value.Name}</li>`;
      if(node.children)
        result += `<li>${treeToHtml(node.children)}</li>`;
      return result;
    }).join('')
  return `<ul>${listItems}</ul>`
}
```

Here is the solution with a select:

```
function treeToSelect(tree, level) {
  if(!level) level = 0;

  return tree.map(function(node){
    var indentation = "-".repeat(level * 3)
    var result = `<option>${indentation}${node.value.Name}</option>`;
    if(node.children)
      result += treeToSelect(node.children, level + 1);
    return result;
  }).join('')
}
```

For the example above, just the options will be generated, so you just have to put it inside a select tag.

You can adjust the indentation with the character that you want and choose how many times it will appear each level by adjusting the level multiplier.

`var indentation = "-".repeat(level * 3);`

Check the live example: https://jsfiddle.net/tercio_garcia/fd08pbo3/4/

Comment: Wow you are amazing,,, what if need to make it select menu,, nested also...

Comment: But there is issue,, u can see we need to add ul before 3rd level

Comment: Hi there! If you inspect the html you see that actually the ul is being created, but for some reason the browser stops differentiating ul from li at the 3rd level.

Comment: You can create a select with optgroup to nest you data, but it only supports 2 levels. Maybe this answer will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44367559/3621569.

Comment: O dont need for select option, i need the below ...every loop increase - - dashes <select>
    <option>select me</option>
    <option>&nbsp;me indented</option>
    <option>&nbsp;&nbsp;even more indentation</option>
</select>

Comment: I updated my answer. I hope this solves you problem :)

Comment: Yes it work but just simple thing for select menu...i need to pass id and make if condition inside loop if node.value.id = 2 ..then i will select the option will id 2...i tried it but did not work

Comment: I think i can do it by dom right? No need to tuch ur code?